# Debezium heartbeat is not committing LSN

Tags: debezium

We have 13 (Amazon RDS) monitored databases by debezium deployed in a Kafka Connect cluster.
What's happening right now is that 1 of this 13 databases has a replication slot which has an increasing lag.

12 databases has 10 to 120 kB lag, while one has > 700 MB at this moment.

Using

```
SELECT slot_name, 
       pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), restart_lsn)) as replicationSlotLag, 
       pg_size_pretty(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_current_wal_lsn(), confirmed_flush_lsn)) as confirmedLag,
       active
FROM pg_replication_slots;
```

[image: replication slot lag]

The replication slot is active; I checked the connector status (`GET kafka-connect:8083/<connector-name>/status`) and both Connector and Tasks are in RUNNING state.

To add more information, we have enabled heartbeat and `heartbeat.action.query` to periodically insert a dummy event in outbox table, so I expect to receive a new change every 10 seconds for each monitored database

We already tried to:

- Check logs for heartbeat thread failure, but we didn't see any exception
- Restart the cluster, but the lag is still there
- Check the related heartbeat topic for the lagging database and there are no messages there, even after cluster restart

Anyone has some idea on what's happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that executing `heartbeat.action.query` manually on the lagging database does the trick... Still don't know why or when it happens